# Why isn't there an AppPackage folder on the azure build agent when building UWP whereas there is one on my machine?

Tags: uwp, azure-pipelines

When I create a UWP package on my machine, it creates an `AppPackages` folder which contains the my app `appxbundle` file as well as a `Depedencies` folder. However, when buidling through an Azure Agent, such `AppPackages`folder is not there. Yet I need the `Depedencies` folder it contains.

How can I tell the azure agent to create the `AppPackages` folder?

Updates:

I use yml:

```
msbuildArgs: '/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(BuildPlatform)" /p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\" /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload'
```

I have access to the machine where the agent runs and cannot find the `AppPackages` folder

Update 2:

The log says that the `AppxPackages` folder path is
`C:\Users\MyLogin\Desktop\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.160.0\_work\1\a\AppxPackages`
yet when I navigate to that path on the private agent, it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why isn't there an AppPackage folder on the azure build agent when building UWP whereas there is one on my machine?

I could create the `AppPackages` folder with Azure Devops by using the MSBuild build task.
The MSBuild arguments are:

```
/p:Configuration=Release;AppxBundle=Always;AppxBundlePlatforms="x86|x64|ARM"
```

[image]

Then I copy and publish that folder, I could get the `Depedencies` folder in the build summary:

[image]

**Update:**

> - I use yml: msbuildArgs: '`/p:AppxBundlePlatforms="$(BuildPlatform)"    /p:AppxPackageDir="$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\" /p:AppxBundle=Always /p:UapAppxPackageBuildMode=StoreUpload`'
> - I have access to the machine where the agent runs and cannot find the    AppPackages folder

I suppose you are using your private agent. Since you set the MSBuild argument `AppxPackageDir` as `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)\AppxPackages\\`, so the local path should be in your agent installation directory on the machine where the agent runs. It is like: `c:\<YourPrivateFolder>\1\a`.

So, make sure you are using the private agent, and you have check the correct folder. On the other hand, you also could check the build log to check the local path of your `AppxPackages`.

Besides, you can use the [Publish build artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task to publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines, so that we could get that folder on the build summary tab:

[image]

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: @François, I have updated my answer with more details, you can check if it helps you. If not, please share your build log to me, so that I could find the reason for your question.

Comment: @François, Thanks you reply. Since the log says the AppxPackages folder path, would you please monitor if monitor whether there is file generation in that path when you build your project? And also you could check your build log if there any copy item like copy `"...\ARM\Microsoft.NET.CoreRuntime.1.1.appx" to "C:\Users\MyLogin\Desktop\..."`. Or if you not have permission to save file in that path. BTW, have you test it with Publish build artifacts task? If yes, what is the result?

Comment: I don't understand why the AppxPackages folder is not there on my private agent. Yet publishing that folder enabled me to access its content via artifacts.